Pyautogui Screenshot not working when converted to .exe
I developed a simple script in python where I get the coords from a object on the screen and than screenshot in a region close to the object coordinate.
Follow the code:
import pyautogui
from PIL import Image


def locate_on_screen(image):
    global x,y
    try:
        if pyautogui.locateOnScreen(image, confidence=0.8):
            ec2 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(image, confidence=0.8)
            x, y = pyautogui.center(ec2)
        return x, y
    except:
        pass
x, y = locate_on_screen('life.png')
        print(x,y)
        answer2 = pyautogui.screenshot('answer2.png', region=(x+80, y-10, 80, 19))

On PyCharm works perfectly, but when I use PyInstaller, the app is not able to screenshot.
I already installed all modules and dependencies before build .exe, the app is opening correctly, also checked if APP (.exe) is locating the object on the screen using print(x,y) and is also fine, but the answer2.png (screenshot) file is not generated.
Can anyone help me to figure out what is happening?

Pyinstaller run in a folder in C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp, so is possible you have to specify the save's full path

How can I run pyinstaller on this path if the .py file is not there ?

Read the documentation here.

I just figure out the problem. Was related to the Pyautogui version, I dont know but for some reason the lastest version PyAutoGUI-0.9.54 was causing this issue, I just replace the version to the current that I was using on my code PyAutoGUI==0.9.40 and worked.
